# SELECT returning really old data

Tags: sql-server

We have an SQL server instance that gets used by 3 application servers. The other day, one of those 3 servers seemingly got stale data from the database, whereas the other 2 servers were fine.

The query is literally this:

```
SELECT a, b, c, State FROM t WITH(NOLOCK);
```

The `State` of the rows get updated once a day, but more than one hour after the change, above query returned old values for `State`, but only for that one server.

I know `WITH(NOLOCK)` means the DB can return uncommitted data, it can omit and even duplicate rows. But surely not 1 hour after a transaction was committed and read successfully by the other clients!?

I'm at a loss here - is there any explanation for this? Any idea how to debug this further?

The only idea I have come up with so far is an `SqlConnection` coming from the pool with some dirty state on it ("ideally", in a "Read committed" transaction that had read the table in question before its state changed). So far, it's a wild theory, and I wouldn't expect a transaction to stay alive for more than an hour, but according to the logs, earlier that day 4 queries timed out after (the custom timeout interval of) 120 seconds, so that leaves hope for some connections to have been put back into the pool in an unclean state...

**Update** All my attempts to create a dirty connection in the pool that could get reused and show the expected behavior have failed so far. Even when an `SqlConnection` with a transaction with isolation level repeatable-read is used, the `WITH(NOLOCK)` will override the isolation level and read uncommitted values, so my idea does not seem to get me any closer to reproducing the strange behavior.

Comment: how these db connected? mirroring with each other? same data over three servers?

Comment: why are you using WITH(NOLOCK)? is there a lot of blocking and deadlocks involved? If all application server is accessing the same database instance I think data is not committed yet.

Comment: 1. Check the connection strings are using the exact same server name, i.e.: not some using an FQDN while others are just using a hostname. 2. Check the HOSTS file for any entries that may be causing connections to a different IP address. 3. Open a command prompt on each application server and confirm via `ipconfig /all` that they are using the same DNS server(s). 4. Query each DNS server with `nslookup -type=a YourSqlServerName IpAddressOfTheDNSServer` and ensure they all return the same IP address. 5. Check that the Initial Catalog/Database name in each connection string is the same.

Comment: In short, expect unexpected behaviour with `NOLOCK`. Your problem description is pretty vague so I don't think this is anything we can help with.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm no fan of `NOLOCK`, but it should not make a query return data that is hours old - on the contrary, it would be the antidote to e.g. a repeatable-read scenario. See also **Update** in my question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Good suggestions! All connections are using the same connection string - it's a app-wide configuration. Will check your other suggestions.

Comment: Given a description of "three application servers seemingly got stale data from the database", I think it's worth considering that the issue may be in application logic rather than the database.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Read again: It's not "three application servers", but "one of three ..."

Comment: Fair enough. My main point is that the issue may be elsewhere